# Testers unable to install application

Tags: iphone, ios-provisioning

I've sent my iphone application to my testers and all but one complain that the get error OxE8003FFE when they sync their devices. They are not able to install and run the application.
I'm using an ad hoc distribution provisioning profile and all of the testers devices are included in the profile.
I'm not sure how to proceed and would really appreciate any help you might be to give.

One more interesting bit of information: The program is a universal iPad/iPhone application. My testers are able to install it on their iPads but not their iPhones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some back and forth with DTS I managed to fix this issue.

The problem was that I was compiling for armv7 only which caused the installation to fail on armv6 machines.

Another interesting bit, the default universal project template and iphone projects converted to universal will compile for both architectures by default, this didn't happen for me bacause my project was initially an iPad only project which I converted manually (since there are no automatic tools for this) to be iPhone/iPad universal, this is the probable reason for this setting being incorrect in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Did you properly add entitlements.plist, and uncheck the box therein?

I would recommend having one device locally that you deploy to through iTunes (not building through XCode), to test that the IPA file will work for other testers.  That may mean buying an iPod touch, even the very oldest one will do (if you are targeting 3.x users).

Comment: Thanks. I will try tinkering with the entitlements.plist and see if that helps.

I have an old iPod touch but I'm targeting iOS 4 so it's no good. I wish I know how to "clean" my iPhone so I could test these issues locally but removing all provisioning profiles and the program don't seem to affect anything and the program just installs without a problem.

Comment: No Luck. This seems to have no affect whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to right click your package, find a file embedded provisioning profile and open it with TextEdit. See that the name of the profile you've signed your application is indeed of that of ad-hoc.

After that be sure you sent this file (embedded provisioning profile) along with your ad-hoc build to your testers, because they have to install it on their devices, it's not being done automatically and w/o that profile your ad-hoc build will not sync to the device.

Comment: I'm using build and archive. AFAIK the profile is included in the ipa. I saw no mention of having to install the provisioning profile in Apple's current documentation (I know it was there in the past).

Comment: May be it doesn't say it in apple's documentation, but I know that I've been constantly asked to send the profile to my testers in order to install it on their devices. You can try and install it on your device w/o installing first a profile. Just delete an ad-hoc profile from your device, add your ad-hoc build to iTunes and try to sync.

Comment: Alternatively, you can tell them to unzip the .ipa and install Payload/MyApp.app/embedded.mobileProvision, but that's silly when you could just do it automatically.

Comment: Sending the profile along with the ipa file didn't help. As expected.